# Keyboard not working chromebook unity 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, touchpad, chromebook

I was playing around with some settings and added carried out the following command in the shell window on my chromebook:

sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t keyboard -u

I already had trusty installed but was trying to get the volume keys working better.

Now when I login the touchpad works, but the keyboard and touchpad keys don't.  Any way to reverse the above to get it all working again?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of trial and error but the following worked:

sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t unity-desktop -u

must have reinstalled the bits the command above broke